# Working with Arrays and Pointers in ANSI C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I just started learning C and now face some issues. I wanted to create a small address book. The theory is simple: Creating a structure with the address book logic and initializing a field of this structure.

This is my structure:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    char first_name[15];
    char number[15];
} t_person;
```

This is global. In my main function I create a field/array:

```
t_person persons[MAX_RECORDS]; // MAX_RECORDS = 30
```

I face the following problem: I want to call a function, which handles the logic for adding a new person. But I'm confused with adresses/pointers, etc.

Calling the Function:

```
addEntry(&persons); // Passing the Array to the Function
```

The Function itself:

```
void addEntry(t_person *persons)
{

    int i = 0; // I know this won't work, because adding
               // a new person will overwrite the previous one
               // Just for testing

    printf("Name: ");
    gets(&persons[i].name);
    printf("First Name: ");
    gets(&persons[i].first_name);
    printf("Number: ");
    gets(&persons[i].number);
}
```

I understand, that my function awaits a pointer to t_person, but I pass an array of t_person. But I fail to understand, how to modify my function to to accept an array of t_person WITHOUT making it a global. I want to handle this in my main function.

Any tips for me?

Comment: addEntry(&persons[0]);

Comment: @Nunchy the fact is that the & is not needed, persons already stores the address of the array of struct. If you pass the array to the function the array doesn't need to be global if is defined in the caller function.

Comment: Ok...you're right it isn't needed - it works, though so meh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add at a particular index so you can pass like this -

```
addEntry(&persons[i]); // Passing the Array to the Function
                       // start i from 0 to n-1 (for example)
```

This index `i` will be changed in calling function itself . So you don't need to track index and worry about it in your function `addEntry` .

And instead of using `gets` use `fgets` -

```
fgets(persons->name,sizeof persons->name,stdin);
```

Similarly for all in your function `addEntry`.

> how to modify my function to accept an array of `t_person` WITHOUT making it a global. I want to handle this in my main function.

You don't need to make it global . Declare it in `main` and then pass it your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `persons` as array and you can push on it using `addEntry(&persons[i]);` with a loop, you program will be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_RECORDS 30

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    char first_name[15];
    char number[15];
} t_person;

void addEntry(t_person *persons)
{
    //gets is deprecated because it's dangerous, it may cause buffer overflow, it recommanded to use fgets
    printf("Name: ");
    fgets(persons->name, sizeof(persons->name), stdin);
    //gets(persons->name);
    printf("First Name: ");
    fgets(persons->first_name, sizeof(persons->first_name), stdin);
    //gets(persons->first_name);
    printf("Number: ");
    fgets(persons->number, sizeof(persons->number), stdin);
    //gets(persons->number);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    t_person persons[MAX_RECORDS]; // MAX_RECORDS = 30
    int i = 0;

    while( i < MAX_RECORDS)
    {
        addEntry(&persons[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```